# Linker errors when compiling a templated class definition

Tags: c++, templates, linker, g++

I'm trying to compile a small program that utilizes a templated Bag class. It is organized as follows:

```
// main.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "bag.h"

int main() {
    Bag<std::string> bag;

    bag.add("cheese");
    bag.add("milk");
    bag.add("eggs");
    bag.add("butter");
    bag.add("orange juice");

    std::cout << bag.getCount() << std::endl;

    return 0;
};
```

```
// bag.h

#ifndef _BAG
#define _BAG

#include <stdexcept>

const size_t _MAX_SIZE = 5;

template<typename T>
class Bag {
    public:
        Bag();
        int getCount() const;
        bool isEmpty() const;
        bool add(const T& item);

    private:
        size_t count;
        T contents[_MAX_SIZE];
};

#include "bag.cpp"

#endif
```

and

```
// bag.cpp

#include "bag.h"

template<typename T>
Bag<T>::Bag() {
    count = 0;
};

template<typename T>
int Bag<T>::getCount() const {
    return count;
};

template<typename T>
bool Bag<T>::isEmpty() const {
    return !getCount();
};

template<typename T>
bool Bag<T>::add(const T& item) {
    bool flag = count < _MAX_SIZE;
    if (flag) {
        contents[count] = item;
        count++;
    }
    return flag;
};
```

I am using g++ version 11.4.0 to compile. When I type the command `g++ main.cpp bag.cpp` I am shown the error

```
bag.cpp:4:1: error: redefinition of ‘Bag<T>::Bag()’
    4 | Bag<T>::Bag() {
      | ^~~~~~
```

I am using VS Code.

When I remove `#include "bag.cpp"` from `bag.h` I get the error

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /tmp/ccZmwYEn.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `Bag<std::string>::Bag()'
```

and when I remove `#include "bag.h"` from `bag.cpp` I get the error

```
bag.cpp:4:1: error: ‘Bag’ does not name a type
    4 | Bag<T>::Bag() {
      | ^~~
```

I've included the implementation code within the header but I don't like that cheap workaround. Is there something I'm missing? Unsure of how to proceed. I appreciate all the help I can get. Thank you.

Comment: Not a duplicate of [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/495021/7976805), OP already knows that and has included implementation in header.

Comment: `#include "bag.cpp"` - don't do that. bag.h includes bag.cpp that includes bag.h. You get `Bag<T>::Bag()` defined in two translation units.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen It was still a duplicate, because OP defined functions in bag.cpp.

Comment: *When I type the command g++ main.cpp bag.cpp* -- That's your first mistake.  You should not be compiling `bag.cpp`, but instead incorporating it inside of `bag.h`. -- *I've included the implementation code within the header but I don't like that cheap workaround* -- It is not a "cheap workaround" -- that's how templates work.  Do you consider `<vector>`, `<list>`, etc. and how they are set up as "cheap workarounds"?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie maybe my wording could have been better. However, I've always liked the emphasis on separation of concerns. Having a file to contain my class definition and one to contain its implementation is a personal preference that I like to prioritize unless doing so would break a program. Thank you for your response!

Answer (score 2):

Two main issues:

1. You have a circular `#include`. `#include` means a simple copy-and-paste of entire content of the file in place of that directive. And if there's a circular include, that would mean compiler would have to copy-and-paste them infinitely. Remove `#include "bag.h"` from `bag.cpp`.
2. Since `bag.cpp` is not a complete translation unit that can be compiled separately (it's missing definition of `Bag` class due to removed `#include`), it should not be compiled as one. Remove `bag.cpp` from your compilation command.

Third issue that will bite you eventually:

3. You cannot declare global variables in header files like you did with `_MAX_SIZE` (also, that name is [reserved for compiler use](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers), choose something else). It's fine for this program, since you only `#include` that header once, but for anything more complex you will have a One Definition Rule violation. With C++17, you can make it `inline` to remedy that - it will create only one global variable for entire program. Before that, you can make it `static` - each translation unit will have it's own copy, but assuming you only use the value, that won't be much of an issue.

A recommendation:

4. Choose a different extension for your implementation file. `.cpp` means for most people "a translation unit". Your file is not a translation unit, it's part of the header. `.tpp` is a common extension to tell others "this is a template implementation, it's part of a header".

Comment: This did it! Thank you. However, is there a way to get my program to compile without having `#include "bag.cpp"` in `bag.h`? From time to time I see conflicting ideas on whether or not it' is good practice to include the implementation of a class in the class declaration. Either way, I appreciate your help.

Comment: @xvymnp You should not `#include` implementation files. The only exception is templates - compiler needs to see the implementation to generate concrete instantiation of the template (i.e., to change `Bag<T>` to `Bag<std::string>`). The other way is to force instantiations explicitly, but this will limit you to only specific cases that you have set previously. For containers, the only viable option is to have the implementation in the header.

Answer (score 0):

Templated classes and functions should be both declared AND defined in the header file.

Having declarations in `.h` file and definitions in a `.cpp` file will cause those linker errors because compiler won't see the definitions unless you include `.cpp` file from the `.h` file which is a code smell.

Placing both class declaration and definition in a header file is a matter of choice (to be made on a case by case basis if you are working alone, or decided by the team otherwise) as there aren't clear rules or best practices on whether this is more or less preferred compared to separated declarations and definitions.

If you have a simple class where most methods can be inline why bother to separate implementation and then have to maintain / refactor in two places instead of one? Many templates can certainly fall into this category.

If you have a complex class which needs static storage, then separating implementation seems like a good thing to do.

On a side note, please don't use macros for constants in 2024 unless absolutely necessary — use `const` and `constexpr` instead.